# bison/yacc using defines in %union

Tags: makefile, bison, yacc

I have `TOKEN_LEN` defined in a header file `stuff.h`. I'd like to use it in the `%union` section:

```
%union {
    int ival;
    char sval[TOKEN_LEN];
}
```

However, including it in the `%{ ... %}` section just copies that block verbatim, `bison` will error out because `TOKEN_LEN` is not defined.

I can use `flex -DTOKEN_LEN=100 ...` in the makefile but that means `TOKEN_LEN` is defined in two places. Yes, in `flex` as opposed to `bison`!

I tried defining it solely in the makefile like this:

```
DEFS=TOKEN_LEN=100
```

Then using:

```
flex -D${DEFS} ...
bison -D${DEFS} ...
gcc -D${DEFS} ...
```

But `make` doesn't like this for this reason:

```
<command line>:1: error: %define variable 'TOKEN_LEN' is not used
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'stuff' failed
make: *** [stuff] Error 1
```

Is there a solution to this? The preference would be to have `TOKEN_LEN` defined only in `stuff.h`.

Comment: The `-D` option to `bison` does something totally unlike the `-D` option to the C compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this with bison is to use the bison-specific `%code` directive:

```
%code requires {
#include "stuff.h"
}
```

in the top of your bison file.  This will put this include in the bison generated file(s) before the definition of `YYSTYPE` (the `%union`)

Doing this with generic yacc is harder -- you can use the `%{`..`%}` directive for the yacc parser itself, but you also need to ensure you put `#include "stuff.h"` *before* `#include "y.tab.h"` in every file that has the latter include.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it!